# Grid unable to connect to node

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-grid

I am getting below error when i am running my selenium code. Can someone help me how to overcome this issue:

```
Tests run: 1, Failures: 1, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 129.633 sec <<< FAILURE!
GoogleTest(gridtest.GridTest)  Time elapsed: 128.291 sec  <<< FAILURE!
org.openqa.selenium.remote.UnreachableBrowserException: **Could not start a new session. Possible causes are invalid address of the remote server or browser start-up failure.**
Build info: version: '3.6.0', revision: '6fbf3ec767', time: '2017-09-27T15:28:36.4Z'
System info: host: 'XXXXXX', ip: 'XXXXXX', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '2.6.32-696.23.1.el6.x86_64', java.version: '1.8.0_77'
Driver info: driver.version: RemoteWebDriver
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:607)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:217)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:140)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:153)
    at gridtest.GridTest.GoogleTest(GridTest.java:48)
**Caused by: org.apache.http.conn.ConnectTimeoutException: Connect to xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:4444 [xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/yyy.yyy.yyy.yyy, xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/yyy.yyy.yyy.yyy] failed: Connection timed out**
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.connect(DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.java:157)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.connect(PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.java:359)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.establishRoute(MainClientExec.java:381)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.execute(MainClientExec.java:237)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.ProtocolExec.execute(ProtocolExec.java:185)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec.execute(RetryExec.java:89)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RedirectExec.execute(RedirectExec.java:111)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient.doExecute(InternalHttpClient.java:185)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:72)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:56)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.internal.ApacheHttpClient.fallBackExecute(ApacheHttpClient.java:138)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.internal.ApacheHttpClient.execute(ApacheHttpClient.java:86)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:337)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:136)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:142)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:586)
    ... 38 more
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
    at org.apache.http.conn.socket.PlainConnectionSocketFactory.connectSocket(PlainConnectionSocketFactory.java:75)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.connect(DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.java:142)
    ... 53 more
```

Following is my Grid and node configuration.

I have my Jenkins with Selenium plug-in installed. So my hub is started and running in my Jenkins machine.

Host: xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
Port: 4444

Now from my Node machine i started selenium server standalone with role as node and registred the bun

```
C:\Temp>java -jar selenium-server-standalone-3.12.0.jar -role node -hub http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:4444/grid/register -port 17946
```

Once the node is started i can see in node console that the node is registered to Grid.
And also in Jenkins Selenium Grid i can see node connected in Registered Remote Components.

In Selenium Grid configuration also i configured the above port with chrome and started node in Nodes matching configuration.

Below is my simple code:

```
System.out.println("I am in test");

        DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.firefox();

        // say you use the redhat5 label to indicate RHEL5 and the amd64 label to specify the architecture
        //capabilities.setCapability("jenkins.label","RHEL6");
        //capabilities.setCapability("jenkins.label","redhat5 && amd64");
        // Say you want a specific node to thread your request, just specify the node name (it must be running a selenium configuration though)
        //capabilities.setCapability("jenkins.nodeName","(master)");

        //capabilities.setPlatform(Platform.WINDOWS); 
        //System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "Drivers"+File.separator+"chromedriver.exe");
        //System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\chromedriver\\chromedriver.exe");


        System.out.println("I am after setting chromedriver path ");

        remoteWD = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL("http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:4444/wd/hub"), capabilities); 
        //remoteWD = new ChromeDriver(); 

        System.out.println("I am after RMD");

        remoteWD.get("http://www.google.com"); 
        WebElement element = remoteWD.findElement(By.name("q"));
        element.sendKeys("Selenium WebDriver"); 
        element.submit();
        Thread.sleep(10000);
        System.out.println(remoteWD.getTitle());
        remoteWD.quit();
```

Comment: I guess, the port 17946 is blocked in your firewall. please check the fore forwarding is allowed.

Comment: @Uday Update the question with both the commands for starting the Grid _Hub_ and _Node_ and only the minimal code to reproduce the issue for a quicker analysis

Comment: @Murthi, I am hoping the security engineering team is opened the port on Hub to communicate with Node. So, still there be possibility of this port blocked at Firewall? What other points to need to ask for network team?

Comment: @Debanjan, as i said Hub is run from the Selenium plug-in, so for Grid we need not to provide any command. For node also i have mentioned in the above.

Comment: I resolved my issue by providing the actual Jenkins server name in the script and it started working. As there are some security restrictions, they are not allowing me to point "new URL("http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:4444/wd/hub")". Then i changed the Jenkins URL with my servername like "new URL("http://your jenkins servername:4444/wd/hub")", then it started working. Sharing here as it may help others.

Answer (score 0):

The timeout issue is with the remoteWebDriver which is defaulted to 60 seconds.

Here are the correct settings of it (my example is in C# but it should be the same for you in Java:

```
var timeout = TimeSpan.FromHours(1);
var driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new Uri(node), new BrowserFactory().Create().ToCapabilities(), timeout);
```

I've taken it from a full solution I've done documented in this article:
https://www.tikalk.com/posts/2018/05/02/establishment-of-a-docker-and-chrome-based-selenium-grid-for-web-application-tests/